# Rspec :should vs :expect with regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, rspec

I am running two tests where one fails and one passes. The only difference is the use of `:should` vs `:expect`. Why does one test work and the other doesn't?

Passing Test:

```
it "returns no comma, when the integer is smaller than 1000" do
  separate_comma(random_num(0, 999)).should match /^\d{1,3}$/
end
```

Failing Test:

```
it "explanation" do
  expect(separate_comma(random_num(0, 999))).to match /^\d{1,3}$/
end
```

---

Here's the boring stuff:

```
def random_num(min, max)
   rand(max - min + 1) + min
end

def separate_comma(number, delimiter = ',')
  new = number.to_s.reverse.scan(/.../).join(delimiter)
end
```

Comment: Does it work if the regex is in parens? What's the output of the test?

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer, but a related question. The following spec passes, the essential content copied from the OP's code. Can someone explain why the OP's spec would fail for the `expect` case and why parentheses around the regex would make a difference? (Note: I'm using Ruby 2.0 and RSpec 2.14)

```
def random_num(min, max)
   rand(max - min + 1) + min
end

def separate_comma(number, deliminator = ',')
  new = number.to_s.reverse.scan(/.../).join(deliminator)
end

describe "rspec expectations involving match, regex and no parentheses" do

  it "works for should" do
    separate_comma(random_num(0, 999)).should match /^\d{1,3}$/
  end

  it "works for expect" do
    expect(separate_comma(random_num(0, 999))).to match /^\d{1,3}$/
  end

end
```